# How to make a address autocomplete using google api and cutsom property editor in XAF ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, google-places-api, xaf

I have a xaf web project and I have made a business object named Address, it has field named address. I have to make that address autocomplete when user starts typing in that textbox. It is xaf web application. So i am not able to use html and javascript in that code. I have to use **custom property editor** for that. I have searched evrywhere on the internet and on stackflow But i am not able to find an solution for this in xaf web application. However there  are so many solutions in html and other applications. If I can use that html, javascript in custom editor anyhow, please let me know. If anybody can help in finding solution for that. I will really appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> It is xaf web application. So i am not able to use html and javascript in that code.

That conclusion is inaccurate, because an XAF Web application is a regular ASP.NET WebForms application, which is highly customizable or extendable with your own HTML, JavaScript, custom web user controls or third-party components as well as the underlying platform itself.

> I have to use custom property editor for that.

A PropertyEditor is just a framework's entity or template that is technically a wrapper around visual controls for a particular platform. For instance, in an ASP.NET WebForms app you can inherit your custom property editor class from the WebPropertyEditor one that expects a System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl descendant as its control. That said, it is natural and often easier to use a ready suitable server side control from DevExpress, Microsoft or other vendors as a base, e.g. ASPxGridLookup or ASPxComboBox. Of course, you can also opt for lightweight HTML/JavaScript components loaded with the help of HtmlGenericControl/Panel or other server side controls ([example](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T380965)).

For more implementation details, check out these concepts and tutorials: [one](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/clsDevExpressExpressAppWebEditorsWebPropertyEditortopic), [two](https://documentation.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/clsDevExpressExpressAppEditorsPropertyEditortopic.aspx), [three](https://documentation.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument112678.aspx), [four](https://documentation.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument113097.aspx), [five](https://documentation.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument113610.aspx).

I also recommend you contact the DevExpress support team in case of any further difficulties: https://www.devexpress.com/ask
Bear in mind that this is a commercial product whose use is governed by https://www.devexpress.com/support/eulas/netcomponents.xml

Comment: Hi Dennis, Thank you for helping me. I am still having trouble with it. I have accesses property editor of specific textbox in detail view. Now, I want to embed javascript with it with the help of registerClientScript method.

Comment: Here is my code which is giving me error:This is my code:            private void initNullText(WebPropertyEditor propertyEditor) {   string pp=((ASPxTextBox)propertyEditor.Editor).ClientSideEvents.KeyPress;
if (propertyEditor.ViewEditMode == DevExpress.ExpressApp.Editors.ViewEditMode.Edit {
 ((ASPxTextBox)propertyEditor.Editor).ClientSideEvents.KeyPress= "function(s,e){var autocomplete=new google.maps.places.Autocomplete("+pp+");}"; }  when i run it, it give me error: **js?key=AIzaSyDfnrI-C8aYLREgI8Bl7DkpMKQKKOVEy0M&libraries=places:35 InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement**

Comment: @manvirajrah: I suggest you submit a ticket in the DevExpress Support Center (https://www.devexpress.com/ask) and attach your complete debuggable test project with this implementation along with the screenshots of the UI context and error you received. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @Dennis